# Space between user profile image and content. Bootsrap

Tags: php, html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a forum using php and bootstrap. It works 100%, my only issue is when a user posts in a thread, the post and the user profile images has a big gap. It looks like a padding issue, but there is not padding between them. Any advice would be brilliant

```
echo '<div class="container form">
                <div class="page-header page-heading">
                    <tr class="text-center">
                        <th colspan="2"><h2>' . $row['topic_subject'] .   '</h2></th>
                    </tr> 
                <table class="table forum table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="cell-stat"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead/>';

        //fetch the posts from the database
        $posts_sql = "SELECT
                    posts.post_topic,
                    posts.post_content,
                    posts.post_date,
                    posts.post_by,
                    users.user_id,
                    users.user_name
                FROM
                    posts
                LEFT JOIN
                    users
                ON
                    posts.post_by = users.user_id
                WHERE
                    posts.post_topic = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

        $posts_result = mysql_query($posts_sql);

        if(!$posts_result)
        {
            echo '<tr><td>The posts could not be displayed, please try again  later.</tr></td></table>';
        }
        else
        {

            while($posts_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($posts_result))
            {
                echo '
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="text-center">

                            </td>
                            <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                                <img src="ppp.png"><br>
                                <i class="fa fa-clock-o">
                                </i>
                                <ul class="pull-left user-info">
                                    <li>'
                                        .$posts_row['user_name'].
                                    '</li>'.
                                    '<li>'
                                        . date('d-m-Y H:i',  strtotime($posts_row['post_date'])).
                                    '</li>
                            </td>
                            <td class="pull-right">'.
                                '<p>' 
                                     .htmlentities(stripslashes($posts_row['post_content'])).
                                '</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>';
            }
        }

        if(!$_SESSION['signed_in'])
        {
            echo '<tr><td colspan=2>You must be <a href="signin.php">signed    in</a> to reply. You can also <a href="signup.php">sign up</a> for an account.';
        }
        else
        {
            //show reply box
            echo '<tr><td colspan="2"><h2>Reply:</h2><br />
                <form method="post" action="reply.php?id=' .     $row['topic_id'] . '">
                    <textarea name="reply-content"></textarea><br /><br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit reply" />
                </form></td></tr>';
        }

        //finish the table
        echo '</thead></table>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe try using the Bootstrap Media Object? http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media It's designed to display things like this.

Comment: Any other help with this guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the gap might be as a result `pull-right` applied on the table

```
 <td class="pull-right">'.
          '<p>' 
             .htmlentities(stripslashes($posts_row['post_content'])).
          '</p>
 </td>
```

You might want to remove it completely. If not, try applying `pull-left` to the paragraph instead of table

```
        <td >'.
              '<p class="pull-left">' 
                 .htmlentities(stripslashes($posts_row['post_content'])).
              '</p>
     </td>
```

Comment: No change unfortunately.

Comment: If you are working with Chrome or firefox browser, try editing your html directly in the browser using the developers tool. Press CTRL + SHIFT + I

Comment: html inspector will come up and you will be able to edit your html tag by first selecting the section. Add and remove classes to see how it goes